# Select a row with least value of a column using where and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Sample table:

```
id------user_id------grade_id------time_stamp

1---------100----------1001---------2013-08-29 15:07:38

2---------101----------1002---------2013-08-29 16:07:38

3---------100----------1001---------2013-08-29 17:07:38

4---------102----------1003---------2013-08-29 18:07:38

5---------103----------1004---------2013-08-29 19:07:38

6---------105----------1002---------2013-08-29 20:07:38

6---------100----------1002---------2013-08-29 21:07:38
```

I want to select rows whose `user_id = 100` group by `grade_id` only if its `time_stamp is least` for that particular `grade_id`.

so, from the above table, it should be:

**row 1** because its `time_stamp` is least for that value of **grade_id(1001)**

but not **row 2** because I only want 1 row for a particular **grade_id**

also not **row 6** because that particular **grade_id** `has least value for user_id 105`.

I tried few things, which are too basic and obviously not worth posting.

Thank You

Comment: What database are you using? Some databases have built-in functions for this, others require you to write your own SQL for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try nested queries:

```
SELECT grade_id, COUNT(grade_id) FROM SAMPLE_TABLE ST WHERE time_stamp = (SELECT MIN(time_stamp) FROM SAMPLE_TABLE STT WHERE STT.grade_id = ST.grade_id) AND user_id = 100 GROUP BY grade_id;
```

In this case, the nested query will give you the minimun timestamp for each specific 'grade_id' and you can use it in your WHERE filter.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tableX AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT grade_id, MIN(time_stamp) AS time_stamp
      FROM tableX
      GROUP BY grade_id
    ) AS g
      ON  g.grade_id = t.grade_id
      AND g.time_stamp = t.time_stamp
WHERE t.user_id = 100 ;
```